# How to select relational data on different table by id in laravel

Tags: laravel, model, controller, relation

i Have 3 Table , the name is : user , machine , maintance . this schema like this

> *User
>
> id | name | email | password | created_at | updated_at
>
> 1  | john | A@mail | ******* , etc
>
> *Machine
>
> id | name_machine | created_at | updated_at
>
> 1 | shock | .....etc
>
> *Maintance
>
> id | Machine_id | user_id | question | status | created_at |
>   updated_at
>
> 1 | .........1........ |.......1......| blablabla etc ..

now i want to show data on table "Maintance" with show data "name" (user table) and name_machine( machine table) by id .

this is my controller and my view

```
 public function show($id)
{
    $maintance = Maintance::all();
    return view('users.view',['maintance' => $maintance]);
}
```

my view

```
<table class="table table-hover">
              <tbody><tr>
                <th>Machine</th>
                <th>Question</th>
                <th>User Input</th>
                <th>Action</th>
                <th>Tanggal</th>
              </tr>
              @foreach ($maintance as $i)
              <tr>
                <td>{{ $i->machine_id}} </td>// i want to show name machine here
                <td>{{ $i->Question}}</td>
                <td>{{ $i->user_id}}</td> // name users to 
                <td><span class="label label-primary">Lihat Data</span></td>
                <td>{{ $i->created_at}}</td>
              </tr>
              @endforeach
            </tbody></table>
```

this view data is not having error ,but i dont know how to showing this data from different table . can someone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Maintance` model belows,

```
public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
public function machine(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Machine::class);
}
```

assuming that your Model have these above relations.

and do the below to get your data,

```
$maintance = Maintance::with(['user','machine'])->get();
```

and in your view

```
<table class="table table-hover">
          <tbody><tr>
            <th>Machine</th>
            <th>Question</th>
            <th>User Input</th>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>Tanggal</th>
          </tr>
          @foreach ($maintance as $i)
          <tr>
            <td>{{ $i->machine->machine_name}} </td>// i want to show name machine here
            <td>{{ $i->Question}}</td>
            <td>{{ $i->user->name}}</td> // name users to 
            <td><span class="label label-primary">Lihat Data</span></td>
            <td>{{ $i->created_at}}</td>
          </tr>
          @endforeach
        </tbody></table>
```

Comment: sir can you tell/explain me why u use belongsTo on Models ?

Comment: I used belongsTo to set up a relation between your tables. look at your table `maintance`. it have two foreign key `user_id` and `machine_id`, foreign_key are refer to its parent table using `belongsTo` / `belongsToMany` relation ship. Here `user` table and `machine` table has `id` as primary key and assumes it is `auto increment`. obviously one entry in `maintance` table has one entry in each of its parent table.